# Have to click "show more items" to see any items

Tags: azure-boards

This is the kind of crazy situation we often see trying to use Azure Boards (a browser-based web-app):
[image]

The lane is shown totally empty except for the "show more items" link... in this case clicking it shows only a single item. Isn't the point to stop the lane getting crowded, which clearly isn't the case here.

We're constantly getting caught out by this in stand-up meetings that most of our stories in a sprint are not actually visible, it's becoming a bit of a joke in the same vein as "you're on Mute!" in online meetings, is there some way to fix it?

Comment: It looks that the microsoft-devops as it's a mix of company name and fragment of product family name (azure devops). As the name of the web app is Azure Boards, I renamed it to [tag:azure-boards]. Once said that, please checkout the [Azure Boards documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/), share what you found and why it didn't meet your needs as is suggestedi n [ask]. Also in order to reduce back and forth, please add the name and version of your operative systema and web browser.